# Default photo not showing up for staging environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a site on my staging environment in heroku. Anytime a user doesn't have an image associated with them there will be a default image showing. The image is stored in my asset/image directory. I don't think this is a case of not having an S3 bucket since other photos in the image directory are showing properly.

My model is set up

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, 
                                     :default_url =>
                                      ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("noimage.jpg")
```

Is my issue with how I'm asking for the image file or something relating to paperclip.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, which works for me:

```
default_url: ->(attachment) {ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("noimage.jpg")}
```

Note that I have my image file in `/assets/images`

If that doesn't work, there are other variations too..seems to be a ongoing issue with paperclip default_url